# PHP script error 500 but the query works on phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an Update query without external parameters:

```
UPDATE APPOGGIO 
INNER JOIN ANAGRAFICHE
ON CONCAT(ANAGRAFICHE.cognome,' ',ANAGRAFICHE.nome)=APPOGGIO.atleta
SET APPOGGIO.cognome=ANAGRAFICHE.cognome,
APPOGGIO.nome=ANAGRAFICHE.nome,
APPOGGIO.sex =ANAGRAFICHE.sex,
APPOGGIO.num_tess=ANAGRAFICHE.num_tess,
APPOGGIO.anno = DATE_FORMAT(ANAGRAFICHE.data_nascita, '%Y'),
APPOGGIO.lev= 5;
```

In phpmyadmin works great (less than 1 second), but if I put it in a php script, using pdo statement,
it returns

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
> misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please
> contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error
> occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the
> error. More information about this error may be available in the
> server error log.

I look on the server error log and it returns:

> [Thu Feb 17 21:57:34.544034 2022] [fcgid:warn] [pid 3431427:tid
> 140095573161728] [client 79.26.89.4:57420] mod_fcgid: read data
> timeout in 40 seconds, referer:
> https://www.atleticainumbria.it/DEVELOP/TEST.php [Thu Feb 17
> 21:57:34.544084 2022] [core:error] [pid 3431427:tid 140095573161728]
> [client 79.26.89.4:57420] End of script output before headers:
> TEST.php, referer: https://www.atleticainumbria.it/DEVELOP/TEST.php

It's possible that takes more than 40 sec?

The script is

```
$sql="INSERT INTO APPOGGIO (gara, pos, atleta, categoria, squadra, tempo, media) VALUES (:gara, :pos, :atleta, :categoria, :squadra, :tempo, :media)"; 
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":gara", $gara);
$stmt->bindParam(":pos", $pos);
$stmt->bindParam(":atleta", $atleta);
$stmt->bindParam(":categoria", $cat);
$stmt->bindParam(":squadra", $squadraFILE);
$stmt->bindParam(":tempo", $tempo);
$stmt->bindParam(":media", $media);
if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
echo "L'atleta $atleta non è stato inserito!";
print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
$errIns=1;
}
$sql1="UPDATE APPOGGIO 
INNER JOIN ANAGRAFICHE
ON CONCAT(ANAGRAFICHE.cognome,' ',ANAGRAFICHE.nome)=APPOGGIO.atleta
SET APPOGGIO.cognome=ANAGRAFICHE.cognome,
APPOGGIO.nome=ANAGRAFICHE.nome,
APPOGGIO.sex =ANAGRAFICHE.sex,
APPOGGIO.num_tess=ANAGRAFICHE.num_tess,
APPOGGIO.anno = DATE_FORMAT(ANAGRAFICHE.data_nascita, '%Y'),
APPOGGIO.lev= 5";
$stmt1 = $db->prepare($sql1);
$stmt1->execute();
```

Comment: Please show us your PHP script.

Comment: I doubt the answer can be found on the generic 500 internal server error page.
The problem could be more related to the mod_fcgid timeout, see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mod_fcgid%3A+read+data+timeout